# Leaflet marker in polygon

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I made a map with Leaflet.js with GeoJSON data and all it's right. But when i want put a marker in a Polygon i cant.

I leave a clipping of my code.
Everything works except the marker

````
          data: squareParkData,
          color: "black",
          fillColor: "green",
          fillOpacity: 0.3,
          weight: 1,
          onEachFeature:onEachFeature,
          pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, { icon: municipalDependenceIcon });
          }
        }) ```

Thanks
````

Answer (score 1):

According to the specifications, it seems like the pointToLayer is used for geomtery type 'points'.

> Points are handled differently than polylines and polygons

You can use the (onEachFeature's) feature geometries and add a new marker to the layer.

To compute for the center of multiple points, you can use TurfJS
https://turfjs.org/docs/#centroid